# SQL query keeps getting timed out on Workbench. Other simple queries are working. Even this one was working yesterday

Tags: sql, session-timeout

I am trying to get the first landing page url using a table consisting of the website session ids, pageview ids within the session and the urls.

SELECT
website_session_id,website_pageview_id,pageview_url

FROM website_pageviews

WHERE created_at < '2012-06-14' **AND website_pageview_id IN
(select MIN(website_pageview_id) FROM website_pageviews GROUP BY website_session_id)**

As soon as I add the bold part to get the relevant data, the query runs out of time after 30 s. This wasn't happening yesterday. In the tutorial video, temporary table has been used to perform the same task but I thought that this was concise. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hey ZON,
Try running this `select MIN(website_pageview_id) FROM website_pageviews GROUP BY website_session_id `
And see how much time is it taking .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest window functions instead:

```
SELECT website_session_id, website_pageview_id, pageview_url
FROM (SELECT wp.*,
             MIN(website_pageview_id) OVER (PARTITION BY website_session_id) as min_website_session_id
      FROM website_pageviews wp
     ) wp
WHERE created_at < '2012-06-14' AND
      min_website_pageview_id = website_pageview_id;
```

Comment: This seems a bit advanced with respect to what I know. I will try to understand it. Can you please tell me what might be wrong with my query?

Comment: @ZON . . . `IN` is not always optimized particularly well.